# adb cant connect to windows WSA

Tags: adb, windows-subsystem-for-android

I am trying to use adb to connect to my Android subsystem in windows (WSA). But when using
`adb connect 172.23.178.142` (IP is correct)

[image: WSA IP address]

This error occurs:
[image: Error]

Comment: check the port, example adb connect 172.xx.xx.xx:12345

Answer (score 0):

For connecting with wsa through adb, you will need to open wsa settings (green icon), go to Developer and activate Developer mode. Then you will connect adb with the given ip adress on the same location.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue

**Solution**

Launch the **Files** application. See the image below

[image]

Connect the adb using command `adb connect 127.0.0.1:58526`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an IPv4 Address starting with "192.168" instead of using the "127.0.0.1" loopback address. Additionally, go to the WSA settings to explore the "Experimental features" and make sure to enable "Local network access".

In general, this is how to connect WSA using the Android Debug Bridge (adb):

1. Turn on "Windows Subsystem for Android" → "Advanced Settings" → "Developer mode"
2. Turn on "Windows Subsystem for Android" → "Experimental features" → "Local network access"
3. Click on "Amazon Appstore" or "Manage developer settings" to start the emulator
4. Toggle the "Developer mode" setting to see your `adb` connection URL
5. Install `adb` (comes with the [Android SDK Platform-Tools](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools))
6. Find your local IPv4 address using `ipconfig` in the Windows PowerShell
7. Try to connect with the `adb`, Example: `adb connect 192.168.178.70:58526`

There is a post with screenshots [here](https://typescript.tv/hands-on/what-is-the-windows-subsystem-for-android-wsa/) and a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCKNH5ymBN0) showing these steps in detail.

Comment: Ver 2308.40000.4.0 seems to have broken this. I used to able to do this without a problem. Now I can not connect, and get the same error as above. And yes, I've done all the step listed above. One thing I have noticed is that the pop-up for request for authorization does not occur. Revoking the authorization doesn't solve this issue. I have re-installed WSA and still get the same problem. Quite annoying for a dev.